# Node starts my server, so does gulp, but gulp doesn't find any paths

Tags: node.js, gulp

I am sure this is something small, but I am unable to figure it out. Node, nodemon and gulp use app.js to start my server so I am not sure why one way works while gulp does not. If I start my server using:

nodemon app.js or
node app.js it starts fine and when I use the path localhost:1337 in the browser it does what it is supposed to do.

When I use the command:

gulp

it says that it started the server but when I navigate to localhost:1337 it does not display anything other than "Cannot GET /" and none of my sources are showing in the inspector. I still get the message that "the port is listening" as indicated in my app.js console.log. My gulpfile is as follows:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');

gulp.task('nodemon', function(){
    nodemon({
    script: './app/app.js'
    })

});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('*.js', ['nodemon']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['nodemon']);
```

---

```
my app.js file is:

express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('../views'));
app.use(express.static('../bower_components/angular'));
app.use(express.static('./directives'));

app.listen(1337);
console.log("The port is listening");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Cannot GET /' being displayed when you go to `localhost:1337` is Express's generic message when a request is made against a route that is `undefined`. A route needs to be defined for the pages that you want to serve. You need to add a Route to handle the request to the root of your app at `http://localhost:1337/`.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    // return back a message
    res.send('Welcome!');

});
```

Place the above snippet above `app.listen()` and the message "Welcome!" will be displayed.

To serve a view in an html file you need to add a view engine so Express knows how to render the file. Additionally, the `views` property needs to be configured so Express knows where to render your views from. The example below uses [ejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs) to just handle plain html files and not worry about a template engine like `jade`.

```
app.use('views', path.join(__dirname + '/views'));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.use('view engine', 'html');
```

Now we can use the [render](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.render) function on the [res](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res) object to send our index.html file:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});
```

This a [guide](http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html) from ExpressJS on how to implement routing in Express.

Comment: That works in the sense that it does print Welcome to the screen, but it still does not show my sources or use the index.html file I have in the views directory. Why does using the command "nodemon app.js" from the terminal allow the server to grab the index.html in my views directory when using "gulp" runs the default Nodemon to start app.js and returns nothing? They are both running the same file but gulp (which is using nodemon to start app.js) does not give me the same results as running "nodemon app.js"

Comment: both gulp and plain terminal are doing the exact same thing, they are both executing your `app.js` file using the nodemon app. The issue isn't with gulp vs terminal from what I can see, based on the source that you've sent it seems like your `app.js` file is missing the routing. I've updated the answer above to hopefully better address your question about serving your views.