# Express Server returns Cannot Get when trying to access index.html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

I referred to the previously asked question on this but couldnt resolve it. I have Express server installed and trying to run Index.html file through it.
But I am getting 'Cannot GET /' as the response.

Here is the server.js through which I calling the index.html

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('index.html', function (req, res) {

  app.use("/", express.static(__dirname));
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You aren't properly implementing your Express route.See this question and the subsequent answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33116084/node-starts-my-server-so-does-gulp-but-gulp-doesnt-find-any-paths/33116116#33116116

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access a directory on your hosted site, say the root directory of localhost on port 8080, using `http://localhost:8080/` for URL, the browser does not send a request for 'index.html` to the server and just uses whatever the server sends back.

It's the express static middleware which in response to a browser request with no filename will check if the folder exists and (by default) return any index.html contained in the folder. So your line of code for routing,  `app.get('index.html')` never executes, and the browser gives you the error message.

Here's a mini static express server if you want to try it.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('../public')); // path to your public directory

var server = app.listen(8080, function () {
   var host = server.address().address;
   var port = server.address().port;
   console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a simple static, folder-as-server kind of thing, you can do it without express way like "/public":

```
var fs = require("fs");
var host = "localhost";
var port = 8000;
var express = require("express");

var app = express();
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname));
app.listen(port, host);
```

I put this in the file `express.js`, so that is in the same folder than `index.html` (even associated `.js` with node.exe). This way the folder is the root of the server.